# GenerateResetPasswordTokenAsync missing in Asp.net Identity 1.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-identity

The method IdentityManager.Passwords.GenerateResetPasswordTokenAsync is missing from Asp.net Identity 1.1 when upgraded the project from Visual Studio 2013 RC to RTM. Could not find any substitute or documentation for this functionality. Not sure whether PasswordHasher can help.

Please share any tried and tested sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is available right now in the nightly builds available on MyGet (https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetwebstacknightly) and should be in the next release of Asp.Net Identity.

Comment: Any idea how soon this will be part of pre-/stable release on NuGet?

Comment: @Santosh, Unfortunately I don't. Hopefully it won't be long.

Answer (score 1):

It's been removed from the RTW and will reappear in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

You can start using password reset functionality if you [pull down the nightly.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/09/asp-net-identity-nuget-packages-for-the-nightly-builds-are-available-on-myget.aspx)

[image]